# How to do PyTorch F.cross_entropy?

Tags: pytorch, cross-entropy

I have output with dimension `batch_size x 14 x 100` (14 object x 100 classes). I want to do cross-entropy loss with ground truth indices provided with dimension `batch_size x 14`. However, when I use `torch.functional.cross_entropy`, I get the error message that says Expected target size `[15, 100]`, got `[15, 14]`. Does anyone know what the reason is?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [cross entropy documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html)

For higher dim inputs, the inputs and targets are expected to be of size `(N, C, d_1, ... d_k)` and `(N, d_1, ... d_k)` where `N` is the batch size and `C` is the number of classes.

Your output should be of shape `batch_size x 100 x 14` rather than `batch_size x 14 x 100`